# Finite subgroups and $H^2 = H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and $H$ a subset of $G$.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $H^2 = H$. I'm interested in what holds if $H^2 = H$.
It's easy to verify that $H$ is a semigroup. If $H$ is finite, $H$ is also a monoid:

Assume $e \notin H$. Fix any $h \in H$. Then $h \notin hH$. Since $hH \subseteq H^2 = H$, we have $|hH| < |H|$, a contradiction. Thus $e \in H$.

If $H$ is infinite, then $H$ needn't be a monoid: $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ is a group, and $(\mathbb{Q}^+, +)$ isn't a monoid, even though $\mathbb{Q}^+ + \mathbb{Q}^+ = \mathbb{Q}^+$.

But what if $H$ is finite; is $H$ perhaps a group?

Thank you!

Comment: Wondering if this applies to the situation $H := \{x \in \Bbb{Z}/n : x^2 = 1 \pmod d\}$, where $d$ fixed is some divisor $1\lt d \mid n$.   This is clearly a mult. submonoid of $\Bbb{Z}/n^{\times}$ the group of units modulo $n$.  Clearly contains $1$ and so $H^2 = H$.  Therefore $H$ is necessarily a sub*group* of $\Bbb{Z}/n^{\times}$ and not simply a submonoid.  @Shaun

Comment: But let $H$ be as you define and let $G$ be $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ in the above. What am I missing, @DanielDonnelly?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3862053/104041), @DanielDonnelly :)

Comment: @Shaun that comment doesn't hold because $H \not\subset G$ necessarily.  So these are just monoids.  But when $d = n$ it's a group.

Comment: I don't follow, @DanielDonnelly. If $X$ is a submonoid of a group $Y$, then $X\subseteq Y$.

Comment: $X$ sits in the monoid of $\Bbb{Z}/n$ which is only a group if $n$ is prime.  So in my case $n  = p_m\# = p_1p_2 \cdots p_r$.  So in the case $d = n$ the monoid $H_d$ is indeed a subset of the units modulo $n$, but for $d \lt n$, it's either strictly or at least usually not a subset of the units.  For example, $5^2 = 1 \pmod 2$, but modulo $10 = 2\cdot 5$ we have that $5^2 = 5 \pmod {10}$ which is definitely not equal to $1 \pmod {10}$.  Therefore $H_{n,d} = H_{10,2}\not\subset\Bbb{Z}/10^{\times}$ while $H_{10, 10}$ of course is a subgroup because $x^2 = 1 \pmod{10}\implies x$ is a unit!

Answer (score 6):

If $H$ is finite, then $H$ is a group.

Note that if $h \in H$, then $\{h,h^2,h^3,\ldots\} \subset H$, which implies that $h$ must have finite order (say $n$). In particular, $h^{-1} = h^{n-1} \in H$, so $H$ is closed under taking inverses. Since also $e \in H$ and $H$ is closed under multiplication, $H$ is a group.

Comment: This is misleadingly phrased. $h$ necessarily has finite order since it has finite order in $G$. You probably mean to say "this implies that the orbit of $h$ under the action is entirely contained within $H$"

Comment: $G$ is not assumed to be finite, so I do not think anything can be said a priori about the order of $h$ in $G$

Comment: ah, reading failure on my part

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight variation to your proof. Fix $h\in H$. Consider the injection $f: hH\to H$. Since both sets are finite and $|hH| = |H|$, $f$ is a bijection. Hence $e\in H$ has a preimage under $f$, which means there exists a $h'\in H$ such that $hh' = e$, so $H$ is closed under taking inverses.