# Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. If $X^2=X$ and $X$ is finite, then $X\le G$; a proof explanation.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

This is a [proof-explanation](/questions/tagged/proof-explanation) question concerning the proof of **Theorem 3.18(ii)** of Rose's *"A Course on Group Theory"*. The closest thing I could find via Approach0 is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083216/104041), which does not answer my question.

### The Theorem:

*Paraphrased:*

> Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. If $X^2=X$ and $X$ is finite, then $X\le G$.

(Here $X^2=\{ab\mid a,b\in X\}$.)

### The Problem Step in the Proof:

> Let $x\in X$. Then $xX\subseteq X^2=X$. Since $X$ is a finite set and $\;\color{red}{{\rm clearly }\; \lvert xX\rvert=\lvert X\rvert}$, it follows that $xX=X$.

I don't understand why $$\lvert xX\rvert=\lvert X\rvert.$$

---

The rest of the proof is alright. I'll include it here for clarity and completeness.

> Therefore $x\in xX$ and so $x=xe$ for some $e\in X$. But then, in $G$, $1=x^{-1}x=e\in X$. Now $1\in xX$ and so $1=xy$ for some $y\in X$. Then, in $G$, $x^{-1}=y\in X$. Since also $X^2\subseteq X$, this shows that $X\le G$.

### Thoughts:

Is the problem step a consequence of $xX\subseteq X^2=X$ by definition of $X^2$, since $$xX=\{xs\mid s\in X\}?$$

How do I get the reverse inclusion?

Plus, they need not be the same set, since that's what the sentence uses $\lvert xX\rvert=\lvert X\rvert$ to conclude.

An idea I have is to establish a bijection between $xX$ and $X$. This is more difficult than it looks at first, though, since, at this stage, at least *a priori*, it could be that $x^{-1}\notin X$.

Please help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a bijection between $xX$ and $X$: the map $f:X\to xX:y\mapsto xy$ is a bijection whose inverse is the map $f^{-1}:xX\to X:y\mapsto x^{-1}y$. The fact that $x^{-1}$ may not be in $X$ is irrelevant: we still know that if $y\in xX$, there is some $z\in X$ such that $y=xz$, and therefore $x^{-1}y=z$ is in $X$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you :)

Comment: @Shaun: You’re welcome.